# Javascript. Изменить структуру объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите, как изменить структуру данных с такой

```
{
    "key_1": [
        ["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9", "99"]
    ],
    "key_2": [
        ["10", "20"], ["30", "40"], ["50", "60"], ["70", "80"], ["90", "990"]
    ]
}
```

На такую

```
[
    {
        "key_1": ["1", "2"],
        "key_2": ["10", "20"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["3", "4"],
        "key_2": ["30", "40"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["5", "6"],
        "key_2": ["50", "60"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["7", "8"],
        "key_2": ["70", "80"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["9", "99"],
        "key_2": ["90", "990"]
    }
]
```

То есть элементы из исходных массивов должны попасть в конечный массив с учётом их индексов: нулевые элементы в нулевой, первые - в первый и так далее.
К сожалению, я не очень силён пока что в JS и самостоятельно получилось сделать с помощью этого кода

```
var final = [];
for (key in temp1) {
    temp1[key].reduce((a, current) => {
        let b = new Object();
        Object.assign(b, {
            [key]: current
        });
        final.push(b);
        return a;
    }, [])
}
```

такую структуру, но это не то, что нужно

```
[
    {
        "key_1": ["1", "2"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["3", "4"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["5", "6"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["7", "8"]
    },
    {
        "key_1": ["9", "90"]
    },
    {
        "key_2": ["10", "20"]
    },
    {
        "key_2": ["30", "40"]
    },
    {
        "key_2": ["50", "60"]
    },
    {
        "key_2": ["70", "80"]
    },
    {
        "key_2": ["90", "990"]
    }
]
```

Массивы key_1 и key_2 в исходном объекте могут быть разной длины. Оставшиеся элементы(из исходного key_1 или key_2) должны также попасть в конечный массив. Будет просто новый элемент массива такого вида `{"key_2": ["90", "990"]}` или `{"key_1": ["9", "90"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе неправильно был использован метод [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

1. Нужно собирать все в один массив, в данном случае `final`, поэтому можно передать его в качестве начального значения, вместо пустого массива
2. на каждой итерации можно устанавливать элемент массива по конкретному индексу, соответствующему текущему элементу (третий параметр, передаваемый в коллбэк)
3. Если по указанному индексу еще нет элемента - установить его
4. Если есть, расширить с помощью [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

В итоге можно получить следующее:

```js
var data = {
  "key_1": [
    ["1", "2"],
    ["3", "4"],
    ["5", "6"],
    ["7", "8"],
    ["9", "99"]
  ],
  "key_2": [
    ["10", "20"],
    ["30", "40"],
    ["50", "60"],
    ["70", "80"],
    ["90", "990"],
    ["100", "1000"]
  ]
};

var final = [];
for (key in data) {
  final = data[key].reduce((acc, current, index) => {
    acc[index] = Object.assign(acc[index] || {}, {
      [key]: current
    });
    return acc;
  }, final);
}

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Это то, что нужно! Спасибо! И ещё спасибо за то, что нормально и по полочкам все объяснили.

Answer (score 1):

Для любого кол-ва объектов и значений объектов.

1. Находим самое длинное значение (массива).
2. На основе максимального значения создаём массив-счётчик для перебора.
3. Перебирая все ключи заполняем значениями, которые формируются по текущему индексу.
4. Если длина какого-то значения (массива) исходного объекта меньше, пропускаем.

```js
const data = {
  "key_1": [
    ["1", "2"],
    ["3", "4"],
    ["5", "6"],
    ["7", "8"],
    ["9", "99"]
  ],
  "key_2": [
    ["10", "20"],
    ["30", "40"],
    ["50", "60"],
    ["70", "80"],
    ["90", "990"]
  ],
  "key_3": [
    ["100", "200"],
    ["300", "400"],
    ["500", "600"]
  ],
  "key_4": [
    ["146"]
  ]
};

const maxLength = Math.max(...Object.keys(data).map(item => data[item].length));
const result = [...(Array(maxLength).keys())].reduce((arr, _, index) => {
  const current = Object.keys(data).reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (index < data[item].length) obj[item] = data[item][index];
    return obj;
  }, {});
  arr.push(current);
  return arr;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

При необходимости можно загнать в одну строку.

```js
const data = {
  "key_1": [
    ["1", "2"],
    ["3", "4"],
    ["5", "6"],
    ["7", "8"],
    ["9", "99"]
  ],
  "key_2": [
    ["10", "20"],
    ["30", "40"],
    ["50", "60"],
    ["70", "80"],
    ["90", "990"]
  ],
  "key_3": [
    ["100", "200"],
    ["300", "400"],
    ["500", "600"]
  ],
  "key_4": [
    ["146"]
  ]
};

const result = [...(Array(Math.max(...Object.keys(data).map(item => data[item].length))).keys())].reduce((arr, _, index) => (_ = Object.keys(data).reduce((obj, item) => (index < data[item].length && (obj[item] = data[item][index]), obj), {}), arr.push(_), arr), []);
console.log(result);
```